# External dll is not adding in docker build command in .net core API

Tags: .net, docker, asp.net-core, dockerfile

I added a external dll(TestProgram.dll) to my .net core API, when I run "docker build -t TestDockerImage" its failed at last and error is:

```
Controllers\EmployeeController.cs(4,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'TestProgram' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [C:\src\MyRestAPI.csproj]
```

Here is my docker file:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:3.1 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:3.1 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["RestAPI.csproj", "."]
RUN dotnet restore "./RestAPI.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."
RUN dotnet build "RestAPI.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "RestAPI.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "RestAPI.dll"]
```

How to solve this issue?

Comment: Is it a Linux image? And is the library is compatible with Linux image?

Comment: Hi, actually this is a windows image

Comment: You have the `COPY . .` instruction, but I'm wondering if that's actually including the external DLL you need. Where is the DLL stored on your host file system? Is it contained within the build context directory of your docker build? If not, it wouldn't end up getting copied into the container.

Comment: Actually I have these dll files in a project folder ("Shared"),then how can I use copy command into dockerfile? any example